# Linux JNA-based affinity not usable because it failed to load

Tags: azure, ubuntu-16.04, jna, chronicle-queue

I have a listener project implemented on java that consumes the data from kafka and pushes into the Vanilla Chronicle queue. I am using the java libraries of jna, jna-platform version 4.4.0 and chronicle queue version 3.6.4. When I run the project on Windows it successfully consumes and pushes the data into the queue. However when I run it on "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS" that is located on Azure VM while pushing the data into the queue it fails. And on also when I run it on my local ubuntu that is in VMware it also succesfully runs. Anyone has an idea what the problem is? The execution log is below:

```
*WARN  [main] (net.openhft.affinity.Affinity:149):
 Linux JNA-based affinity not usable because it failed to load! Reason: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.openhft.affinity.Affinity.isLinuxJNAAffinityUsable(Affinity.java:113)
    at net.openhft.affinity.Affinity.<clinit>(Affinity.java:52)
    at net.openhft.affinity.AffinitySupport.getThreadId(AffinitySupport.java:26)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.VanillaChronicle$VanillaAppenderImpl.startExcerpt(VanillaChronicle.java:628)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.VanillaChronicle$VanillaAppenderImpl.startExcerpt(VanillaChronicle.java:615)
    at com.myproject.queue.DataQueueManager.add(DataQueueManager.java:55)
    at com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener.initKafka(myprojectListener.java:67)
    at com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener.start(myprojectListener.java:43)
    at com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener.main(myprojectListener.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: sched_getaffinity(0, (8) , cpuset) failed; errno=22
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.LinuxHelper.sched_getaffinity(LinuxHelper.java:61)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.LinuxJNAAffinity.getAffinity(LinuxJNAAffinity.java:62)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.LinuxJNAAffinity.<clinit>(LinuxJNAAffinity.java:49)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [22] H"
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:390)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.$Proxy7.sched_getaffinity(Unknown Source)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.LinuxHelper.sched_getaffinity(LinuxHelper.java:56)
    ... 11 more
07.09.2017 12:58:28.631 WARN  [main] (net.openhft.affinity.Affinity:149):
 Posix JNA-based affinity not usable because it failed to load! Reason: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.openhft.affinity.Affinity.isPosixJNAAffinityUsable(Affinity.java:99)
    at net.openhft.affinity.Affinity.<clinit>(Affinity.java:56)
    at net.openhft.affinity.AffinitySupport.getThreadId(AffinitySupport.java:26)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.VanillaChronicle$VanillaAppenderImpl.startExcerpt(VanillaChronicle.java:628)
    at net.openhft.chronicle.VanillaChronicle$VanillaAppenderImpl.startExcerpt(VanillaChronicle.java:615)
    at com.myproject.queue.DataQueueManager.add(DataQueueManager.java:55)
    at com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener.initKafka(myprojectListener.java:67)
    at com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener.start(myprojectListener.java:43)
    at com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener.main(myprojectListener.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: sched_getaffinity((4) , &(allocated@0x7f2ba436c7e0 (4 bytes) (com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference@a437470b)) ) errorNo=22
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.PosixJNAAffinity.getAffinity(PosixJNAAffinity.java:125)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.PosixJNAAffinity.<clinit>(PosixJNAAffinity.java:64)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [22] ý
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:390)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:323)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:236)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.$Proxy8.sched_getaffinity(Unknown Source)
    at net.openhft.affinity.impl.PosixJNAAffinity.getAffinity(PosixJNAAffinity.java:117)
    ... 10 more
07.09.2017 12:58:28.633 INFO  [main] (net.openhft.affinity.Affinity:61):
 Using dummy affinity control implementation
07.09.2017 12:58:28.634 ERROR [main] (com.myproject.listener.myprojectListener:71):
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException*
```

Comment: I can say we have tried to run this on Azure VM. In my experience, affinity only helps on isolated cpus on bare metal machines.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [22] H"
```

Error code 22 from the linux source is `EINVAL` [1].

Looking at the `man` page for the function `sched_getaffinity` shows the reason for `EINVAL` being returned:

`EINVAL (sched_getaffinity() and, in kernels before 2.6.9, sched_setaffinity()) cpusetsize is smaller than the size of the affinity mask used by the kernel.`

This could be an issue in the library, but is more likely due to the runtime environment and the way that the VM infrastructure is reporting/using CPU masks.

As Peter has pointed out, the value of setting process affinity in a virtualised environment is questionable.

1) http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.4.84/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/errno-base.h#L25